# Google Charts - animation transition example

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Take a looka t my JS below, for my drawChart function for a google chart.  This works as I expected.  HOWEVER, because `var chart ...` is inside the drawChart function, the animations do not work - instead google thinks it's creating a brand new chart each time, and just refreshes the chart.

I would like to do something like in their examples, where the data **moves** according to my settings (1000ms, default easing: linear).  Examples are here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation

If I pull out the `var chart ...` from the `drawChart` function, I get a "*Chart not defined*" error.  Appreciate the help from anyone who has worked with google charts a lot.  Thanks for the help.

```
var chart = "notSet";
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(setGoogleData);
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
newValue = 0;
var data = [];
function setGoogleData(){
  data[0] = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSON_DATA_LOCATED_HERE);
  data[1] = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSON_DATA_LOCATED_HERE);
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('stopByTripChart'));
}
function drawChart() {
  if(chart == "notSet"){
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('stopByTripChart'));
  }
  var options = {"title":"Average Load Summary","titlePosition":"in","width":1100,"height":700,"hAxis.slantedTextAngle":90,"hAxis.position":"out","pointSize":5,"animation.duration":1000,"animation.easing":"linear","hAxis.showTextEvery":1,"hAxis.title":"Stops"};
  chart.draw(data[newValue], options);
}
function changeChart(){
  newValue = document.getElementById("chartNumber").value;
  drawChart();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never tried Google charts myself, but I think such a code would work:

```
var chart = null;
function drawChart() {
  if(chart === null){
     chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('stopByTripChart'));
  }
  var options = {"title":"Average Load Summary",
                 "titlePosition":"in",
                 "width":1100,
                 "height":700,
                 "hAxis" :{"slantedTextAngle":90,
                           "position":"out",
                           "showTextEvery":1,
                           "title":"Stops"},
                 "pointSize":5,
                 "animation":{"duration":1000,
                              "easing": 'out'};
  chart.draw(data[newValue], options);
}
function changeChart(){
  newValue = document.getElementById("chartNumber").value;
  drawChart();
}
```

Otherwise, the error about chart not being defined might come from the fact that you might have placed your code before the load of the google library. Hence, chart was called before the google objects existed (tho it's hard to tell with just that snippet).

Comment: Good idea.    I am calling google chart object ahead of all of this with the callback after the object is fully loaded, so that shouldn't be the issue.  I'll give your if statement a try.  Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately, no luck here.  I'm going to update my post to show the full code...  I tried with a string and with null, and neither case worked.  The updated code in the question above shows it with a string, "notSet".

Comment: I'll take a look at it then :)

Comment: I don't know if it's just an error coming from the copy/past and SO formatting, but you'll have to remove the "var" in front of the "chart"s inside functions. Otherwise, the "chart" variable is only a local one.

Comment: you're right, it was MY copy/paste error... ha.  Ok so that is working, but still the transitions don't seem to be working.  I have no clue why not though.  It just reloads the graph, rather abruptly.

Comment: It migth come from the fact that you're passing the animations parameters as a dotted string. I edited my answer in order to adopt a better formatting for the options variable.

Comment: wow, you're right.  I thought that was the correct way to do it, but I guess it all needs to be in an array like that.  Thanks for the help, this solved it.

Comment: This ended up working for me as well. Pulling out the chart variable above draw chart and setting it only if it's null does indeed keep it from creating a new chart every time you call drawChart(). Seems pretty obvious but things can get messy with the Google visuals.